# Adobe flash can't run code in a frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Ok, I'm fairly new to Flash, and I was trying to code some ActionScript now for the last two days. I can't a simple piece of code to work:

```
stop();
```

So... pretty simple right? ;)

I have a 10 frame animation, and I'm trying to make the animation stop at frame 5. So I select frame 5 from my timeline and then I open the action menu and I simply write stop(); in the window. When I run it I get the following error message:

```
In ActionScript 3.0 code cannot be placed directly on objects. Please select an object or use the Code Snippet panel to apply code to the current selection on stage.
```

I totally understand this is a simple question and the answer might be obvious, but I can't find it...

Thanks

EDIT:

I tried debugging it, and it works when in the debugger but not when in flash...

Comment: Make sure you don't have an object selected, by rather a frame, when you put the code in

Comment: Once the code is in properly,  a little 'a' will appear on the frame. if you're not seeing that 'a' right now, then your code isn't where you think it is.

Comment: I put the code in the frame, but I have a text field in my frame, and when I click this text field the action windows show the same code I  put in the frame. If I try to remove this code, it also remove the one I wrote for the frame

Comment: And I don't know if it's a keyframe changes something

Comment: That's very strange. It shouldn't even let you put code on an object when you have an AS3 project open.  Silly question, but have you tried restarting flash? or creating a new AS3 project and trying the same stop command? sometimes .fla's can get messed up.

Comment: post your FLA if you can

Comment: you probably have the `pin` selected in your action script window so no matter what you click on whatever you have pinned is showing

Answer (score 2):

You're putting the code "on" the object, not allowed in AS3 (thx god).
To avoid it, create a new layer and name it "code" (or whatever you want), and put the code in it